# For an Elder Polyp, do each of its tentacles get its own attack of opportunity?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, opportunity-attack

My PCs have an upcoming bottle with an Elder Polyp (Tome of Horrors III 10). The monster is copied into an adventure path I'm running and has 4 tentacles. The Elder Polyp does not have Combat Reflexes or a similar feat that provides attacks of opportunity, but it does have 4 tentacles.

Should each tentacle be given its own attack of opportunity, or would it still only be one attack of opportunity per round for the creature?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One attack of opportunity a round.

Consider a player playing a hypothetical broody drow dual-wielding matched scimitars: if they asked for two AoO because they have two swords, you'd probably say no without hesitation. The Polyp is no different: lacking any special abilities that say otherwise, merely having extra attacking limbs doesn't grant more than one AoO.

Answer (score 2):

If it does not have combat reflexes and does not state anywhere in the stat block that it gets extra attacks of opportunity, it only gets 1.

The Flying polyp has 4 tentacles and specifically needs combat reflexes to give it more opportunity attacks: http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/aberrations/flying-polyp